# How to pause and continue a simple javascript created animation

Tags: javascript, function, animation

I am trying to create a game where you have to move a ball on a platform. At the start of the game, the ball is dropped on the platform and then you can move it around with the arrow keys. This is al working, no problems here. Please see [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bCj2/) (click the 1 to start).

As you can see, the platform has a yellow tile. When you move the ball on it an animation will start (the disappearing of the ball). This animation will not stop if you roll the ball off the blue tile. Here lies the problem. I want to stop the animation if the ball is off the yellow platform and continue if you roll it on again. So I need to pause it and continue it. How to do this?

**Some code:**

```
this.isOn = function (x, y) {
        var isOnIt = this.active && this.x == x && this.y == y;
        if (isOnIt) {
            if (this.ends) {
                ball.end(this.x, this.y);
            }
            if (this.breaks) {
                $('#roller div').eq(this.indx+1).data('tile', this).animate({opacity: 0}, 1300, this.breakAway);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This `isOn` function executes code when the ball is on a tile. `this.breaks` is the code part when rolling on the yellow tile and makes it disappear. The following function removes the tile by making it `false`:

```
this.breakAway = function() {
        var tile = $(this).data('tile');
        tile.active = false;
        plane.breaked(tile.x, tile.y);
    };
```

Hope someone can help me out! Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stop the animation by calling jQuery method `stop`; make sure parameter `jumpToEnd` is false so that the animation appears to be paused.

To resume, start a whole new animation. For its initial state, you will need to know where the previous animation was stopped. Make a callback function that keeps track of the animation state. When creating an animation (jQuery method `animate`), you can specify a callback function `step`. Its parameter `now` is the current animation state; let the callback function copy that value to a global variable, so you always have the latest value at hand.

HTH.

- http://api.jquery.com/animate/
- http://api.jquery.com/stop/

**EDIT:** I forked your fiddle to demonstrate the stop/start trick:
http://jsfiddle.net/283Kz/2/

Changes to your original code are minimal.

First of all, I added a method `isOff` to tile; all it does is stop the animation.

```
this.isOff = function (x, y) {
    if (this.active && this.x == x && this.y == y) {
        $('#roller div').eq(this.indx+1).data('tile', this).stop();
    }
};
```

The method is called by plane's method `move`, from the same loop where `isOn` is called. This required a slight refactoring.

```
if (oldTileX != tileX || oldTileY != tileY) {
    var newIndex;
    for (var i=0, lng = tiles.length; i<lng; i++) {
        tiles[i].isOff(oldTileX, oldTileY);
        if (tiles[i].isOn(tileX, tileY)) {
            onAny = true;
            newIndex = i;
            // no break to ensure isOff gets called too
            // (consequently, we need a separate variable newIndex)
        }
    }
    if (onAny === false) {
        ball.die();
        return;
    }
    tiles[newIndex].modify();
    oldTileX = tileX;
    oldTileY = tileY;
}
```

In tile's method `isOn`, I replaced the fixed duration `1300` by a calculation `1300 * obj.css('opacity')` as a compensation for a possible earlier animation that already consumed the tile partially.

```
if (this.breaks) {
    var obj = $('#roller div').eq(this.indx+1).data('tile', this);
    obj.animate({opacity: 0}, 1300 * obj.css('opacity'), this.breakAway);
}
```

Notice I did not need a callback function after all because I could use CSS property *opacity* instead of a custom variable.

Comment: Could you show me how to do this in a fiddle? I've also searched with google for these query solutions but all use events like `click` or `hover` and my code doesn't. I am struggling of how to get it in :(

Comment: Thanks for this extended answer, it really helps me understanding this all better. Ow and extra kudos for the fixed duration calculation, hadn't thought of that! Thanks again!